# combining sdl and directx buffer

Tags: directx, sdl

I am able to render the DirectX and SDL content on the SDL Window but when the content of DirectX is rendered it hides the content of SDL and when the content of SDL is rendered it hides the content of DirectX. This is because the DirectX and SDL buffers are different.

is there any way that i can store the two contents in a single buffer(either of DirectX or SDL)?or is there any way to cope up with?

Comment: How do you render direct x? Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to render DirectX content to a texture, copy the pixels over to an SDL texture, and do your SDL rendering with that.

http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut22.html can help with rendering DirectX to a texture, and you can use `SDL_Surface` objects (see `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` and friends) for the SDL side. Be careful with pixel formats as well.

You can also go the reverse direction (which may be easier). Since you're already given an `SDL_Surface` object for the main rendering buffer, you can copy pixel data from that into a new DirectX texture.

Hope this helps - I can post any concrete code later if need be.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'm trying to Combine DirectX11 with SDL2: could you post any code if possible please ?